# How do i change "this" object

Tags: redux, axios

I know the rule that `this` object cant be changed but need an alternative method .

```
var that= this
        axios.get('http://ec2-54-165-240-14.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/api/foodItem').then(function(data){
            console.log("inside axios ",data)
            that.setState({
                items : data,
            });
            var curGroupId = that.props.cartReducer.val;
            var items = that.state.items ;
            var curItems= [];
            for(var i in items){
                if(items[i].food_group_id==curGroupId){
                    curItems.push(items[i]);
                }
            }
            that.setState({
                curItems : curItems
            })

        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
        })
```

I want to update the state in `this` object which is not accessible inside  the `then` function and therefore i have stored `this` object in `that` before the function but i want to apply changes in the `this` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using an arrow function, that way you will have access to `this` inside the inner functions.

```
axios.get('http://ec2-54-165-240-14.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/api/foodItem')
   .then((data) => {
        console.log("inside axios ",data)
        this.setState({  // <---- references to the parent scope
            items : data,
        });
        var curGroupId = that.props.cartReducer.val;
        var items = that.state.items ;
        var curItems= [];
        for(var i in items){
            if(items[i].food_group_id==curGroupId){
                curItems.push(items[i]);
            }
        }
        this.setState({   // this too ;)
            curItems : curItems
        })

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

An arrow function will use the same scope as the parent function, pretty handy for these situations.

One more thing, I don't recommend calling `setState` multiple times. You should call it only once at the end of the callback, when all your data is ready to use.

Comment: Thanks :)
Works for me .
And yes will keep that in mind